# Wifi ESP8266 between to micros

Tags: wifi, esp8266

I would like to transfer data from an 8-bit micro to another 8-bit micro. My question is, can I do it using wifi (ESP8266) without having a router. Can I simply transfer data from one to the other?

Answer (score 3):

If I understood the question correctly, the answer is yes.Provided, both microcontrollers have a UART interface.
ESP8266 can both be an AP and an STA. So router is not needed.And there is a P2P mode too i've heard.

look here.
[ESP8266-transparent-bridge](https://github.com/beckdac/ESP8266-transparent-bridge)

> This is really basic firmware for the ESP that creates a totally
>   transparent TCP socket to ESP UART0 bridge. Characters come in on one
>   interface and go out the other. The totally transparent bridge mode is
>   something that has been missing and is available on higher priced
>   boards.

Comment: If you find this answer useful then please accept it as right answer.